# CSS Sprites - not showing up in IE 8 and 7

Tags: html, css

I looked around for the answers, but I m not sure if my codes are missing something. I would appreciate it if you could guide me or help me.

**Edited per @djlumley's request**

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="container"> 
        <h1 id="logo" class="float-left text-left"><a href="/"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Company Name"/></a></h1>
        <nav id="menu">
          <ul>
              <li class="home"><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
              <li class="events"><a href="#"><span>Diary of Events</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="slider">
      <div class="container"> 
        <div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin slidereel" id="camera_wrap_1">
          <div data-thumb="img/slides/thumbs/1.jpg" data-src="img/slides/1.jpg">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">Camera is a responsive/adaptive slideshow. <em>Try to resize the browser window</em>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-thumb="img/slides/thumbs/2.jpg" data-src="img/slides/2.jpg">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">Camera is a responsive/adaptive slideshow. <em>Try to resize the browser window</em>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-thumb="img/slides/thumbs/3.jpg" data-src="img/slides/3.jpg">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">Camera is a responsive/adaptive slideshow. <em>Try to resize the browser window</em>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--end .container-->
    </div><!--end #slider-->

    <article>
      <div class="container"> 
        <h2>Examples</h2>
          <p>Incorporating</p>
          <div id="corp_container">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="img/logo_comm.png" alt=""/></li>
            <li><img src="img/logo_ent.png" alt=""/></li>
            <li><img src="img/logo_bro.png" alt=""/></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <footer>
      <div class="container"> 
        <div id="keypartners" class="float-left">
          <p>Key Partners</p>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="img/pics_37.jpg" alt=""/>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="img/pics_39.jpg" alt=""/>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="hostedby" class="float-left">
          <p>Hosted by</p>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="img/pics_41.jpg" alt=""/>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="img/pics_43.jpg" alt=""/>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="footernav" class="float-right text-right">
          <ul>
            <li>Disclaimer</li>
            <li>Privacy Policy</li>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Diary of Events</li>
          </ul>

          <div id="copyright">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2012</p>
            <p><strong>Last Updated on</strong> 1 March 2012</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </footer>
  </div><!--#wrapper-->
</body>
```

```css
#wrapper{ width:100%;}

header{background:#fff url(../img/logo_bg.jpg) no-repeat; height:87px; width:100%;display:block;}
header h1#logo{height:20px; margin-top:-10px; width:201px;}
  #menu {float:right;margin-top:35px;width:300px;height:52px; display:block;}
  #menu span{display:none;}
  #menu li, header #menu a{height:52px;display:block;}
  #menu li{float:left; list-style:none;}
  #menu .home a{width:96px;}
  #menu .events a{width:164px;}
  #menu .home a{background:transparent url(../img/navs.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;}
  #menu .events a{background:transparent url(../img/navs.png) no-repeat -96px 0px;}
  #menu .home a:hover{background:transparent url(../img/navs.png) no-repeat -0px -53px;}
  #menu .events a:hover{background:transparent url(../img/navs.png) no-repeat -96px -53px ;}

  #event_header{background:#2dacf1;margin: 0 0 10px 0;padding: 5px 0; width:100%;}


#slider{
    height:400px;
    /* fallback */ background-color: #33b5f3; 
    background-image: url(../img/banner_slider_bg.jpg);
    background-position: center center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */ /* Can't specify a percentage size? Laaaaaame. */ 
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, from(#33b5f3), to(#4dd6f8));
    /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */ background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #33b5f3, #4dd6f8); 
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */ background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #33b5f3, #4dd6f8); 
    /* IE 10 */ background: -ms-radial-gradient(circle, #33b5f3, #4dd6f8); /* Opera cannot do radial gradients yet */ }
}


article{width:100%;}
  article h2{ padding:5px 0;}
  article p{margin: 30px 0 20px 40px;}
  #corp_container{background:#fff url(../img/incorporate.png) no-repeat;height:70px; margin:30px 0 80px 0; width:960px;}
  #corp_container ul{list-style:none;}
  #corp_container ul li{display:inline;padding: 30px 20px 8px 0;}
  #corp_container ul li img {margin-top:-10px;}


footer{width:100%; background:#f4f4f4; overflow:hidden; padding:20px 0 40px 0;}
  #keypartners, footer #hostedby{padding:0 40px 0 0;}
  #keypartners ul,footer #hostedby ul,footer #footernav ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
  #keypartners ul li,footer #hostedby ul li{padding: 5px 40px 0 0;}
  #keypartners ul li,footer #hostedby ul li,footer #footernav ul li{display:inline;}
  #footernav ul li{border:none; height:auto;padding:5px 10px 0 10px; text-align:center;}
  #footernav li + li {border-left: 1px solid #000;}
  #footernav li:last-child {padding-right:0;}
  #copyright{margin:20px 0 10px 0;}
  #copyright p{padding:0;margin:0;line-height:1.5em;}

table,td,tr,th{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-weight:normal;
}

table{font-size:0.8em; margin-bottom:15px; width:100%;}
table td,table th{padding:5px; border:1px solid #fff; border-width:0 1px 1px 0;}
thead th{background:#91c5d4;font-weight:bold; }
thead th[colspan], thead th[rowspan]{background:#66a9bd;}
tbody th {background:#91c5d4;font-weight:bold; text-align:left;}
tbody td{background:#d5eaf0;text-align:center;}
.pink{background:#ffb1b4;}
.red{background:#ff6b71;}
.yellow{background:#fcffa2;}
.purple{background:#f1ddf9;}
.orange{background:#ffc560;}
```

IE 9 and FF show the navigation ok but not IE 8 and 7, why?

Comment: Any changes if you put quotes around the content of your `url` declaration?  `url('../img/_navs.png')`

Comment: @SenorAmor - no it doesn't change anything

Comment: As an aside, putting header in all those selectors serves no purpose and slows the selector matching down.

Comment: Are you using a polyfill for HTML 5 elements in IE? Alternatively, are you explicitly defining header/nav etc as block level elements?

Comment: @djlumley no i dont use polyfill for html elements. yes they should be block level elements. i am guessing i have to define heights and widths and display:block for every elements?

Comment: @Josephine - If you're not defining your header and nav as `display: block` they wont render correctly. You don't need to define an explicit height or width for them (unless your other CSS requires it).

Comment: @djlumley - ok i have edited the header/menu to display block and tested and see that sprites don't appear and also in IE8 the header disappear.

Comment: Can you show some more of your code, so that we can get some context?

Comment: @djlumley, codes are edited above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `a` to [display](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#display-prop) as a block, then give it an appropriate width and height. Because `a` is displayed as inline by standard, it tries to display its content in line of the content around it. Because you have hidden the `span`, the `a` element has no content and thus cannot display inline. Turning into a block or an inline-block allows you to actually display the `a` element as a block regardless its content...

It's this simple: `#menu a { display: block; width: 96px; height:52px; }`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f67mb/), just hover the bottom right blue thing and you'll see it change just like you'd want.

**The reason Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support this is because its CSS doesn't support `nav`**.

When I add support for the nav tag (using a nasty JS hack as well as setting `display:block` on `nav`) and remove all the `#menu`'s from the CSS [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/f67mb/7/). Thus, we need to get that `#menu` selector working.

It's this simple: `<nav><ul id="menu">...</ul></nav>`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f67mb/10/), now it works in Internet Explorer 7 and 8.

Comment: then I cannot use the HTML5 nav?

Comment: @Josephine: I've updated my answer a few times without refreshing the page, both solutions are prepended with `It's this simple:`. The explanation is above that and an example under that. So, you can use the HTML5 `nav` but just have to move the `id="menu"` to the `ul` such that you can select it through CSS. Note that I have added nasty JS code as well as that first line in the CSS...

Comment: I saw the example, I tested it on IE 8 and images appear. But not IE7.. it is strange?

Comment: @Josephine: Tricky one, I only have Internet Explorer 10 which I can put in 8 and 7 mode through the Developer Tools. Have you tried the latest example with the URL that ends in `/10/`, [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/f67mb/10/). If that doesn't work I'm out of tricks to get it working on Internet Explorer 7, but it either has to do with incorrect support of the `nav` element or one of the other CSS attributes. Try to find an example that works in Internet Explorer 7 and try to port that into your site...

Comment: Also consider whether [it would still be worth supporting < 3% of your visitors](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201203-201203-bar)? Some people decide to show a message instead that tells people to upgrade their browser, there is a bunch of explanation to cover that message. Microsoft has stopped IE6 and asks people to stop using IE7, Google themselves have [dropped support](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9217279/Google_to_dump_support_for_Microsoft_s_IE7) as well. See [this related `stop ~IE7`](http://www.google.be/search?q=stop+~ie7) query...

Comment: Wijsum - i did view the latest example ending with /10/ and i typed and see if it worked in IE 8 and 7 - I saw that IE 8 has nav images appearing. When I change to IE 7 mode, it doesn't show up - even with cache being cleared. Here, the visitors do use IE 7 and 8 a lot. I agree with you that the message should tell people to upgrade the browser..only thing is to convince the client or boss?

Comment: @Josephine: Well, the `2 - 3%` could be used as well as [a page like this](http://www.shlomifish.org/no-ie/). But, in the other you'll just have to implement it. **Bottom line:** If you intend to target Internet Explorer 7 and 8, stay away from HTML5 or come up with nasty fixes. So, I've brought you halfway towards better support; but I'm afraid I don't know the other part... :(

Comment: thank you for your help really appreciated it :) Will figure the remain out later.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `span`s don't have any contents, because you gave `display:none` for `span`s and didn't define width for `a`.

Probably most browsers fits `a` to `li` width (`a` has `display:block`), because `li` has `width` property defined, but IE7-8 thinks there's nothing in it so it doesn't display it.

So if you define `width` to `a` it should work properly:

```
header #menu .home a{width:96px;}
header #menu .events a{width:164px;}
```

Comment: I defined width to a but it still doesn't show any css images sprite on IE8 / 7

Answer (score 0):

Hi dude I ran into the same problem some time back and I found out that the issue lies in the css selectors for example in my case I used :nth-child() selector and IE8 does not support it yet and I think the same goes for you the problem is [nav tag is not supported in IE8](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp) so the browser can not access the ID #menu in your css file hence the images do not appear.hope that will help you cheers.